# cursor execute how to create string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I see formatting string using the string formatting is not advisable as it is prone to different problems.

However, I do not like embedding the values in the cursor. execute directly.

How I can build the string separately?

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

I am using python.

Is there a way to separate this?

Comment: Your example looks correct--what error are you seeing?  Also, what database are you using?  Maybe your example works in Postgres, but not in mysql?

Comment: I am trying to find a way not to embed the string in the cursor.execute itself. Can I build the string in some other way? Like java has prepared statement.

Comment: maybe you can put `(var1, var2, var3)` into another `var4` and call `cursor.execute(myquery, var4)`?  Otherwise, I think maybe you might need to clarify your question a bit more

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? those are two very different databases

Comment: Postgres, in fact, aws redshift.